# oracledb para node.js en AIX error°

Tags: nodejs

Que tal estoy tratando de hacer un deploy en un ambiente AIX, usando la librería `oracledb` para `node.js`, me arroja un error de no poder cargar la librería, dentro de mis `node_modules` si esta dicha librería y tengo el instantclient de oracle , dejo muestra del error.

```
throw new Error(nodbUtil.getErrorMessage('NJS-045', nodeInfo));
```

> **Error**: NJS-045: cannot load the oracledb add-on binary for Node.js
>   8.9.4 (aix, ppc64)
>
> Cannot load
>   /opt/IBM/nodeismael/bin/node_modules/oracledb/build/Release/oracledb.node
>   0509-022 Cannot load module
>   /opt/IBM/nodeismael/bin/node_modules/oracledb/build/Release/oracledb.node.
>   0509-026 System error: Cannot run a file that does not have a valid
>   format.
>
> Node-oracledb installation instructions:
>   https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/INSTALL.md
>
> You must have 32-bit Oracle client libraries in your operating system
>   library search path.
>
> If you do not have Oracle Database on this computer, then install an
>   Instant Client Basic or Basic Light package from:
>
> http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/instant-client/overview/index.html
>
> at Object.
>   (/opt/IBM/nodeismael/bin/node_modules/oracledb/lib/oracledb.js:68:13)
>
> at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
>
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
>
> at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
>
> at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
>
> at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
>
> at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
>
> at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
>
> at Object.
>   (/opt/IBM/nodeismael/bin/node_modules/oracledb/index.js:1:80)
>
> at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)

****NOTA: este servidor no tiene salida a Internet.

Comment: Bienvenido a [StackOverflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com), si eres nuevo, realiza el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour), también te recomiendo, que visites [¿Cómo Preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para formular de manera correcta las preguntas, para que estas reciban respuesta; ademas de ser útiles para otras personas.

Comment: ¿Ya probaste a ejecutar `npm rebuild oracledb`?